# Partitioning the data with respect to values in a column in R

Tags: r, split, partition

I have a csv file in the following form:

```
rec | year | ing
----|------|-----
 1  | 2002 | a
 1  | 2002 | b
 1  | 2002 | c
 2  | 2002 | e
 .  |   .  | . 
 .  |   .  | . 
 4  | 2017 | a
```

Now, I want to partition this data by 2-year increments in R. I tried using split function but not sure on how to define increment of 2 years.

Expected output should look like:

```
$0
rec | year | ing
----|------|-----
 1  | 2002 | a
 1  | 2002 | b
 1  | 2002 | c
 2  | 2002 | e
 .  |   .  | . 
 .  |   .  | . 
 3  | 2003 | a 

$1
rec | year | ing
----|------|-----
 5  | 2004 | a
 5  | 2004 | b
 4  | 2004 | c
 4  | 2005 | e
 .  |   .  | . 
 .  |   .  | . 
 6  | 2005 | a
```

Basically, partitioning data by 2 years.

Comment: Can you show the expected output and also some rows with the input data as it is not clear.

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 2):

Divide each year by 2, then floor it to simulate a 2-year period:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep="|",text="
rec|year|ing
1|2002|a
1|2002|b
1|2002|c
2|2002|e
3|2003|a
4|2004|c
4|2004|e
5|2004|a
5|2004|b
6|2005|a
4|2017|a
4|2003|a
")

split(df,floor(df$year/2))
```

If you care what each subset is named, then tweak it to this:

```
split(df,floor(df$year/2)-min(df$year)/2)
```

Comment: I guess another option is `split(df, df$year%/%2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `split` in combination with `cut`.

This will `split` your dataframe in 2 year `seq`uence starting from `min`imum of `year` to the `max`imum.

```
split(df, cut(df$year, seq(min(df$year), max(df$year), 2), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Assuming your dataframe as `df`.